# How to apply 2 animations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, animation

I do not know how to formulate my question.

On my site (Drupal 8 and Bootstrap 4), there is a navigation menu at the top left and a menu at the top right :

https://dev.s1biose.com/fr/boutique/poupette-cacahuete

When I open the navigation menu, the background becomes dark. Same thing for the filter menu.

THE PROBLEM :

If I open the navigation menu without closing it and open the filter menu, there is no dark background.

Why the effect is not displayed ?

There is the same problem with the plus button at the bottom left. I click on the plus button and the bottom is darkened. If I click directly on the menu at the top left, the bottom is not darkened. If I close and open the menu, it works.

Here is my custom JS file :

```
/**
 * @file
 * Global utilities.
 *
 */
(function ($, Drupal) {

  'use strict';

  $(document).click(function (event) {
    if ($(event.target).is('button')) {
      $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
    }
  });

  $(document).click(function (event) {
    if (!$(event.target).is('.navbar-collapse *')) {
      $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
    }
  });

  $('.collapse-navbar-first').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('body').addClass('bs-body-overlay');
  });

  $('.collapse-navbar-first').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('body').removeClass('bs-body-overlay');
  });

  $('.collapse-navbar-second').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('body').addClass('bs-body-overlay');
  });

  $('.collapse-navbar-second').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('body').removeClass('bs-body-overlay');
  });

  $('.collapse-navbar-first').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('.bs-background').addClass('bs-background-overlay');
  });

  $('.collapse-navbar-first').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('.bs-background').removeClass('bs-background-overlay');
  });

  $('.collapse-navbar-second').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('.bs-background').addClass('bs-background-overlay');
  });

  $('.collapse-navbar-second').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('.bs-background').removeClass('bs-background-overlay');
  });

})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

Comment: I would assume, the closing of the previous selection happens after the new one is opened, resulting in the overlay class being removed

Comment: Before doing this `$('body').removeClass('bs-body-overlay');`, you should add a condition to see if the other elements aren't open.

Comment: @pnadalini Good idea, but I start with JS and I'm not a developer (just amateur). Can you explain to me how to do this? Thank you

Comment: @tropcool I just added an answer so you can fix this, I thought of a better idea instead of adding validations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is caused because when it opens the other menu it tries to add the class on the element (which already has it) and then the first menu removes the class when it's closed.

One easy fix you can do for this (probably not the most optimal one) is changing all the `addClass` and `removeClass` to make it `toggleClass` like this:

```
$('.collapse-navbar-first').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
  $('.bs-background').toggleClass('bs-background-overlay');
});
$('.collapse-navbar-first').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
  $('.bs-background').toggleClass('bs-background-overlay');
});
```

And to make the code shorter, you can join both events like this:

```
$('.collapse-navbar-first').on('show.bs.collapse hide.bs.collapse', function () {
  $('.bs-background').toggleClass('bs-background-overlay');
});
```

Comment: Cool, I like it. This might cause a flicker since the class gets toggled on and off and there's a transition on the backdrop.  It's probably fine, as the user is interacting with the page anyway.

Comment: @pnadalini Thank you it works. But I did not understand your remark. Here is my https://pastebin.com/wzedRUVv file. Should I use your method or the second answer ?

Comment: @tropcool what you have in your pastebin file looks ok, if it works you should leave it like that. What I was trying to say was that in [your file](https://pastebin.com/wzedRUVv) lines 44 to 50 can be removed and it should also work

Comment: Also, if you found my answer useful you can [mark it as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @pnadalini Why are these lines useless? This is not the same class because it disables scrolling the body

Comment: Sorry, I must have seen something else, when I was testing in your page I thought it didn't worked but I just noticed it does. I'll remove it from my answer so it doesn't causes confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You're attaching event handlers, it's probably a good idea to group the code that's has the same event as its trigger. (I've done just that in the code snippet).

Event handlers fire in order of the events happening.
The behavior you're seeing is because of the code in each event handler:

1. user clicks left navbar button
   event: `$('.collapse-navbar-first').on('show.bs.collapse')` is fired.
   It adds the `bs-body-overlay`
   ---wait for next user click------
2. user clicks right navbar button
   event `$('.collapse-navbar-second').on('show.bs.collapse)` is fired.
   It also tries to add the `bs-body-overlay`, it's already there though.
   event `$('.collapse-navbar-first').on('hide.bs.collapse')` is fired, because a click outside of the navbar happened
   the `bs-body-overlay` is removed
   then you're left in the state you're describing.

## solution 1: Add css classes for both bars

Basicly the `bs-body-overlay` is used for both the left and right navbar, you could split that class into 2 seperate ones so that they don't interfere with eachother
`bs-body-overlay-left` and `bs-body-overlay-right` apply the same rules, they can co-exsist on the element.

## solution 2: Check if any of the navbars is open

You could also check if any of the navbars is open, and not remove the `bs-body-overlay` class when that is the case.
it get's a bit finnicky to check this though, since bootstrap is still doing the animation.
IE both the left and right bar get the `collapsing` class before they get the `show` class.

## solution 3: Manually keep track of how many bars are open/closed

You could keep a track of the amounts of open/closes and only remove the `bs-body-overlay` when you're certain it can be removed
I would go with solution 1

### css:

```
.bs-body-overlay, .bs-body-overlay-left, .bs-body-overlay-right {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.bs-background-overlay. .bs-background-overlay-left, .bs-background-overlay-right {
    opacity: .8;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1001;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #000;
    transition: .5s ease-out;
}
```

## js:

```
/**
 * @file
 * Global utilities.
 *
 */
(function ($, Drupal) {

  'use strict';

  $(document).click(function (event) {  // fired whenever anywhere is clicked
  
    if ($(event.target).is('button') || !$(event.target).is('.navbar-collapse *')) {
        // hide the elemnt when the click wasn't on the navbar or the button was clicked
      $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
    )   
  });

  $('.collapse-navbar-first').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('body').addClass('bs-body-overlay-left');
    $('.bs-background').addClass('bs-background-overlay-left');
  });

  $('.collapse-navbar-second').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('body').addClass('bs-body-overlay-right');
    $('.bs-background').addClass('bs-background-overlay-right');
  });
  
  $('.collapse-navbar-first').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('body').removeClass('bs-body-overlay-left');
    $('.bs-background').removeClass('bs-background-overlay-left');
  });

  $('.collapse-navbar-second').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('body').removeClass('bs-body-overlay-right');
    $('.bs-background').removeClass('bs-background-overlay-right');
  });
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```